# flutter Getx SharedPrefrences

Tags: flutter

`i have problem and when i want but data in sharedprefrences`

[problem image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSjFT.png)

[problem image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UL5wL.png)

[problem image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbk5w.png)

[problem image 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgT1B.png)

`i want any one show me im new in programing carrer`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.